# Pearson Correlation function returning Nan

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm going through the exercises in "Programming Collective Intelligence", but I'm using JavaScript. I'm having a bit of trouble with the Pearson Correlation algorithm. Here's the function:

```
function rec(object1, object2) {
  var sum1 = 0;
  var sum2 = 0;
  var squareSum1 = 0;
  var squareSum2 = 0;
  var productsSum = 0;
  var i;
  var commonKeys = commonProperties(object1, object2);

  for (i = 0; i >= commonKeys.length; i += 1) {
    sum1 += object1[commonKeys[i]];
    sum2 += object2[commonKeys[i]];

    squareSum1 += Math.pow(object1[commonKeys[i]], 2);
    squareSum2 += Math.pow(object2[commonKeys[i]], 2);

    productsSum += object1[commonKeys[i]] * object2[commonKeys[i]];
  }

  var num1 = productsSum - (sum1 * sum2 / commonKeys.length);
  var num2 = Math.sqrt((squareSum1 - (Math.pow(sum1, 2) / commonKeys.length)) * (squareSum2 - (Math.pow(sum2, 2) / commonKeys.length)));

  return num1 / num2;
}
```

Full JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/98uoy87u/1/). I've run it through JSLint, which is why it may be a bit messy. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: num1 is 0, num2 is 0 and 0/0 = NaN

Comment: You get NaN  because num2 is 0. It's not allowed to divide by zero

Comment: You never enter the for loop as `i < commonKeys.length`, However, that is not the only mistake. I don't think your equations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had a little mistake in the condition "for", var "i" will never be more than commonKeys.length

```
function rec(object1, object2) {
  var sum1 = 0;
  var sum2 = 0;
  var squareSum1 = 0;
  var squareSum2 = 0;
  var productsSum = 0;
  var i;
  var commonKeys = commonProperties(object1, object2);

  for (i = 0; i < commonKeys.length; i += 1) {
    sum1 += object1[commonKeys[i]];
    sum2 += object2[commonKeys[i]];

    squareSum1 += Math.pow(object1[commonKeys[i]], 2);
    squareSum2 += Math.pow(object2[commonKeys[i]], 2);

    productsSum += object1[commonKeys[i]] * object2[commonKeys[i]];
  }

  var num1 = productsSum - (sum1 * sum2 / commonKeys.length);
  var num2 = Math.sqrt((squareSum1 - (Math.pow(sum1, 2) / commonKeys.length)) * (squareSum2 - (Math.pow(sum2, 2) / commonKeys.length)));

  return num1 / num2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/98uoy87u/2/

It works just fine, gives "-1" as answer.

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you never enter the for loop as `i < commonKeys.length`. After correcting this bug, your algorithm is correct. I have verified this for `rec(janeSmith, johnSmith)` using Excel. Excel returns 0.650791373 compared to 0.6507913734559685 from your script.

```js
 function intersection_destructive(a, b) {
   var result = [];
   while (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) {
  if (a[0] < b[0]) {
    a.shift();
  } else if (a[0] > b[0]) {
    b.shift();
  } else /* they're equal */ {
    result.push(a.shift());
    b.shift();
  }
   }

   return result;
 }

 function commonProperties(object1, object2) {
   var keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
   var keys2 = Object.keys(object2);
   return intersection_destructive(keys1, keys2);
 }

 var johnSmith = {
   "Zoolander": 2.5,
   "Batman Begins": 3.5,
   "Deadpool": 4.5,
   "Thor": 1.5
 };

 var janeSmith = {
   "Zoolander": 4.5,
   "Batman Begins": 3,
   "Deadpool": 5,
   "Thor": 2.5,
   "The Avengers": 4,
   "The Internship": 2.5
 };

 var johnDoe = {
  "Zoolander": 4,
   "The Internship": 3,
   "Batman Begins": 4.5,
   "Thor": 5
 };

 function rec(object1, object2) {
   var sum1 = 0;
   var sum2 = 0;
   var squareSum1 = 0;
   var squareSum2 = 0;
   var productsSum = 0;
   var i;
   var commonKeys = commonProperties(object1, object2);

   for (i = 0; i < commonKeys.length; i += 1) {
  sum1 += object1[commonKeys[i]];
  sum2 += object2[commonKeys[i]];

  squareSum1 += Math.pow(object1[commonKeys[i]], 2);
  squareSum2 += Math.pow(object2[commonKeys[i]], 2);

  productsSum += object1[commonKeys[i]] * object2[commonKeys[i]];
   }

   var num1 = productsSum - ((sum1 * sum2) / (commonKeys.length));
   
   
   var num2 = Math.sqrt(((squareSum1 - (Math.pow(sum1, 2)) / commonKeys.length)) * ((squareSum2 - (Math.pow(sum2, 2)) / commonKeys.length)));

   return num1 / num2;
 }

 var value = rec(janeSmith, johnSmith);

 document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<h1>
Value:
</h1>
<p id="value">

</p>
```